# Determine the Function, Image, and Kernel for the Group Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $\phi$: $Z_{50}$ $\mapsto$ $Z_{15}$ is a group homomorphism with $\phi$($7$)=$6$.

a. Determine $\phi$($x$).

b. Determine the image of $\phi$

c. Determine the kernel of $\phi$.

d. Determine $\phi^{-1}$($3$). That is, determine the set of all elements that map to $3$.

What I have so far:

a. Suppose that $\phi$($x$)=$k$$\times$ $x$mod$15$, where $x$$\in$ $Z_{50}$ and $1$$\leq$$k$$\leq$ $14$. We know that $\phi$($7$)=$6$. So $7k$mod$15$=$6$. And so, $k=3$, since $21$mod$15$=$6$.

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi(x) = 3x \mod 15$ then:

b) Only certain elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ will be mapped to, what is this subset? Example, $\phi(x)$ will never map to $1$ since the all must be congruent to a multiple of $3$ since $3|15$.

> $\{0, 3, 6, 9, 12\}$

c) the $\ker(\phi)$ is all the elements that map to the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$. So which $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{50}$ result in $3x\equiv 0\mod 15$?

> $\ker(\phi) = \{ 5k \: | \: 0 \leq k \leq 9\} $ since $\phi(5k) = 15k \equiv 0 \mod 15$  which is true since $15|15k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$

d) Similar to c) but now it is asking for all elements which map to $3$. So $3x \equiv 3 \mod 15$.

> Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism then $\phi(a) + \phi(b) = \phi (a+b)$ and we know that $\phi(1) = 3$. Since $0$ is the identity in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$. Then $\phi(0+1)  = \phi(0) + \phi(1) = \phi(1)$. However $\phi(0)$ is $\ker(\phi)$ so the image of $\phi^{-1}(3)$ must be all the elements of the kernel plus 1 or $\{5k+1 \: | \: 0 \leq k \leq 9 \}$. Another verification is $3(5k+1) = 15k + 3  \equiv 3 \mod 15$.